# Why do I get a read timeout error using python requests

Tags: python, http, python-requests, fiddler

Here's my code:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Host':'www.finishline.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    }

requests.get('http://www.finishline.com/', headers=headers, timeout=5, verify=False)
```

When I run this script I recieve a *read time-out error* when I am expecting a 200 response code. The url also works fine in browser so I can confirm it's not the server.

I used fiddler to sniff the http requests from browser to see whats going. Using fiddler's composer, when I removed the *Connection:keep-alive* header I was able to reproduce the read time-out error.

Is this a requests bug or I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: I cannot replicate, what version of requests?

Comment: FYI, you should not add all these headers yourself, it's request's job.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Sorry, I am using Python 2.7.12 and requests 2.10.0

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Python 2.7.12 and requests 2.11.1

Comment: Try updating requests to the latest then see if the issue persists although I don't think anything major changed.